# BeautifulSoup find_all() to find elements that have one of several acceptable attribute values

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**Primary question**

I know how to use find_all() to retrieve elements that have an attribute with a specific value, but I can't find any examples of how to retrieve elements that have attributes with one of several acceptable values. In my case I'm working with DITA XML and I want to retrieve topicref elements where the scope attribute is one of the following:

- "peer"
- "local"
- None (the attribute doesn't exist)

I wrote a custom function that works, but there must be a smarter way to do this with the functions that are already present in BeautifulSoup. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("./dita_source/envvariables.ditamap","r") as file:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(file)
    file.close()


def isLocal(element):
    if (element.name == "topicref"):
        if (not element.has_attr("scope") or element["scope"] == "local" or element["scope"] == "peer"):
            return True;
    return False;

topicrefs = doc.find_all(isLocal)
```

**Secondary question**

Is there a way to use find_all() with both its standard filters as well as a custom function? I tried `doc.find_all("topicref", isLocal)`, but that didn't work. I had to add the extra `if (element.name == "topicref"):` statement to my custom function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a list as the value of an attribute parameter to `find_all()`, and it will return elements where the attribute matches any of the items in that list:

```
>>> soup.find_all(scope=["row", "col"])
[
    <th scope="col">US $</th>,
    <th scope="col">Euro</th>,
    <th scope="row">Mon – Fri</th>,
    <th scope="row">Sat – Sun</th>,
]
```

... but there's no way to specify "attribute doesn't exist at all" in that list (neither `None` nor an empty string work). So for that, you do need a function.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `topicref` as the first argument (`name`) and pass a function for `scope` keyword argument:

```
def isLocal(scope):
    return scope in (None, "local", "peer")

topicrefs = soup.find_all('topicref', scope=isLocal)
```

---

Or using `lambda`:

```
topicref = soup.find_all(
    'topicref',
    scope=lambda scope: scope in (None, "local", "peer")
)
```